# Sorting Data for Firebase Realtime (Number)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to sort data as 1-2-3-4-5 in Firebase Realtime. If the 3rd data is deleted, I need the new data to be added as 3. It's pretty easy to do this in mysql, but I'm having trouble finding a method for it in firebase. With the code below, I count the data and do this process, but it downloads too much and is costly.

Is there a less costly way to do this?

With this code I calculate which number to add. Then I pass this to the kontrol integer.

```
private void setNextKontrol(){
    kontrolLst = removeDuplicates(kontrolLst);
    Collections.sort(kontrolLst);

    kontrol = 1;

    for(int index=0;index<kontrolLst.size();index++){
        if(kontrolLst.get(index)!=index+1){
            kontrol=index+1;

            return;
        }
    }
    kontrol=kontrolLst.size()+1;
}

public static <T> ArrayList<T> removeDuplicates(ArrayList<T> list)
{
    ArrayList<T> newList = new ArrayList<T>();

    for (T element : list) {

        if (!newList.contains(element)) {

            newList.add(element);
        }
    }

    return newList;
}
```

Here I am downloading all the controldata data.

```
mDatabaseReference.child("/controldata/").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                for (DataSnapshot snap : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    b ne = snap.getValue(b.class);
                    kontrolLst.add(ne.kontrol);

                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```

When a data is inserted, I insert it into controldata as kontrol:1.

```
mDatabaseReference.child("/controldata/").child(key).child("kontrol").setValue(kontrol);
```

End

```
class b{
    public Integer kontrol;
    public String id;
    public void setIds(String id){
        this.id = id;
    }
    public b(){}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert the new data into the first open slot in an existing list, you will either have to read that list (as you're doing now), or have some external knowledge about where the first open slot in the list is.

---

The latter approach means that you keep an extra data structure somewhere (in the database) where you keep track of the open slots. So every time you remove an item from the list, you add that index to the list of open slots:

```
openSlotIndexes: {
  "-Masdhdahk": 3,
  "-Mcasd78e1": 5
}
```

Or simpler, but you have to prefix it with a string to prevent Firebase from interpreting this as an array:

```
openSlotIndexes: {
  "slot3": true,
  "slot6": true
}
```

Then when you need to find an open slot, you read the first item from the list of open slots, write into that slot in your control list, and remove the slot from the list of open slots.

---

Another option is to not fully remove the items from the control list when you delete them, but put a marker value in there, so that you can query for that. For example, say that you use "DELETED" for your marker value, you could query for the first deleted item with:

```
kontrolRef.orderByValue().equalTo("DELETED").limitToFirst(1)
```

Comment: Isn't there a service firebase provides to do this sorting? Doing this process causes a lot of data to be downloaded, and downloading this much data slows down the user's phone.

Comment: I gave two approaches that don't download any additional data in my answer. If I knew of an easier/built-in option, I would have mentioned that. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Hey @mustafasatar Did you get anywhere with this?